# How to use of a self reference type and using alias inside C++ class

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, self-reference

Here is a simple code that I tried to use a self-reference type and using alias at the same time.

```
#include <iostream>
class List {
private:
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node* next;

        node(const int& d=0, struct node* n=nullptr) {
            data = d; next = n;
        }
        ~node() {};
    };
    using pNode = struct node*;
    pNode head;

public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void print() const { std::cout << head->data; }
};

List::List() {
    head = new node{55};
}

int main() {
  List *a = new List;
  a->print();
}
```

This above works fine. However, I'd rather start the code as shown below:

```
class List {
private:
    using pNode = struct node*;
    struct node {
        int data;
        pNode next;
    ...
```

I'd like to place `using pNode = struct node*` before the `struct node` definition such that I can use it inside `struct node` definition as well. I believe that this style of code works fine if I don't use class.

Comment: Avoid adding `typedef`s for pointer types. `const pNode` and `const node*` are very different.

Answer (score 6):

Don't hide pointer semantics in an alias. It's the one "never" advice I always get behind.

And if you agree to only ever use `node*` in your code, then you can just write

```
struct node {
    int data;
    node* next;
    // ..
};
```

C++ introduces a type named `node` with `struct node`, unlike C. So we can use natural syntax.

Answer (score -1):

To use the latter you need to forward declare the struct node like so:

```
struct node;
using pNode = node*;
struct node {
    int data;
    pNode next;
};
```